# Mount NFS volume using podman-compose

Tags: nfs, podman, podman-compose

Hello I am trying to attach nfs volume on my podman container using podman-compose.

However, it always says `mount.nfs4: Failed to resolve server : Name or service not known`. How can I solve?

## Environment

- podman version 4.9.4-dev
- podman-compose version 1.0.6

## Reproduce problem

In my terminal (host OS), it mounts well as you can see.

```bash
$ mount -t nfs XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/mnt/nfs1 /mnt/nfs1
$ mount | grep nfs
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/mnt/nfs1 on /mnt/nfs1 type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA,local_lock=none,addr=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)
```

However, using `podman-compose`, it doesn't well.

`docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  test-nfs:
    image: "registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi:8.9-1136"
    container_name: "test-nfs"
    network_mode: "host"
    privileged: true
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nfs1:/mnt/nfs1

volumes:
  nfs1:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
      device: ":/mnt/nfs1"
```

Using above file, let's run the container.

```bash
$ podman-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up
podman-compose version: 1.0.6
['podman', '--version', '']
using podman version: 4.9.4-dev
** excluding:  set()
['podman', 'ps', '--filter', 'label=io.podman.compose.project=root', '-a', '--format', '{{ index .Labels "io.podman.compose.config-hash"}}']
podman volume inspect root_nfs1 || podman volume create root_nfs1
['podman', 'volume', 'inspect', 'root_nfs1']
podman create --name=test-nfs --label io.podman.compose.config-hash=8c0e9bc14a626047910a2c6fa6ad4eda5b6c094c538ae3a33c19656408c35904 --label io.podman.compose.project=root --label io.podman.compose.version=1.0.6 --label PODMAN_SYSTEMD_UNIT=podman-compose@root.service --label com.docker.compose.project=root --label com.docker.compose.project.working_dir=/root --label com.docker.compose.project.config_files=docker-compose.yaml --label com.docker.compose.container-number=1 --label com.docker.compose.service=test-nfs -v root_nfs1:/mnt/nfs1 --network host --privileged --restart always registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi:8.9-1136
4c0bf4295b8aac36923e78ac26136fb0a5332f989512205fbb15d7c2f173a1e2
exit code: 0
podman start -a test-nfs
Error: unable to start container 4c0bf4295b8aac36923e78ac26136fb0a5332f989512205fbb15d7c2f173a1e2: mounting volume root_nfs1 for container 4c0bf4295b8aac36923e78ac26136fb0a5332f989512205fbb15d7c2f173a1e2: mount.nfs4: Failed to resolve server : Name or service not known

exit code: 125
```

## Question

1. Is there anything I have to do for NFS mount?
2. What is the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way what I missed.

There are two things.

1. If you changed your volume contents in `docker-compose.yaml`, you should remove at the podman volume with command `podman volume rm <volume_name>`
2. Don't put "addr=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" at "o:" (options). It doesn't work (at least in podman) Put it like `device: "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/mnt/nfs1"` as you did at terminal for mount.

Below is my full `.yaml` file. I hope this helps you.

* FYI, I also tested cephfs. It works well.

`docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  test-nfs:
    image: "registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi:8.9-1136"
    container_name: "test-nfs"
    network_mode: "host"
    privileged: true
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nfs-test:/nfs_test
      - cephfs:/images
    entrypoint: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]

volumes:
  nfs-test:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "rw"
      device: "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/mnt/nfs1"
  cephfs:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "ceph"
      o: "name=<PUT_NAME>,secret=<PUT_SECRET>,fs=<CEPH_FS_VOLUME_NAME>"
      device: "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:PORT_NUM:/"
```